# Problema em recuperar dados em uma aplicação laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Minha tabela se constitui da seguinte maneira:

```
╔════════════════════════╗
║        USER            ║
╠═══════════╦════════════╣
║ Id        ║ Integer    ║
║ Name      ║ String     ║
║ Address   ║ String     ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Tenho alguns dados já gravados no banco, exp:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Id        ║ Name      ║ Address       ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ Marcelo   ║ Rua A         ║
║ 2         ║ Ferdinand ║ Rua B         ║
║ 3         ║ Marcelo   ║ Rua A         ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

No meu controller tenho o seguinte método:

```
public function getListUsers()
{
    $users = DB::table("users")->pluck('Name','Address');
    echo json_encode($LatLng);
    return;
    // return response()->json($users);
}
```

Quando exibo a rota que invoca a função do controller, me exibe o seguinte array:

> {"Marcelo":"Rua A","Ferdinand":"Rua B"}

Tentei ainda executar o seguinte:

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $users= DB::table("users")
                ->pluck("name","address");
    print_r(
        DB::getQueryLog()
    );
```

No log, o select executado é o seguinte:

```
 select `user`, `address` from `user`
```

E se eu rodo o mesmo select no meu banco de dados, me trazem os dados correto, que deveria ser algo do tipo:

> [{"name":"Marcelo","Address":"Rua A"},{"name":"Ferdinand","Address":"Rua B"},{"name":"Marcelo","Address":"Rua A"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando a função errada. Após executar a *query* no banco de dados, a função [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) vai transformar seu resultado como um *array* onde o primeiro campo é o valor e o segundo é a *key*.

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
    ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
]);

$plucked = $collection->pluck('name');

$plucked->all();

// ['Desk', 'Chair']
```

Para o que você quer fazer, use [`select()` e `get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects)

```
$users = DB::table("users")->select('Name','Address')->get();

return response()->json($users);
```